# deploy/start/stop JBOSS using CLI

Tags: deployment, jboss, command-line-interface, jboss-cli

I have JBOSS installed on my local server, using it's CLI I am able to deploy/undeploy on a different JBOSS using the command below and providing the respective IP,Port etc wherever I want to deploy.

```
./jboss-cli.sh -c controller=<ip>:<port> --user=<username> --password=<password> --command="deploy <pathToWAR> --server-groups=<virtualservername>"
```

The above command just works fine.

---

Now I am trying restart/stop/start using below command

```
./jboss-cli.sh -c controller=<ip>:<port> --user=<username> --password=<password> --command="reload"
```

But I get an error as below:

```
Missing required argument --host
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using a domain server. You need to supply the host you want to restart. By default it is `master` so you need to add `--host=master` to your `reload` command.

If you want to just reload the server groups, not the host controller, you could use the `restart-servers` operation on the server group you want to restart.

```
/server-group=main-server-group:restart-servers(blocking=true)
```